# XSLT - Two seperate data sources merged into one XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I've have two XML data sources which are completly seperate. UserDetails.xml and UserSites.xml.

The UserDetails.xml contains:

```
<a:UserDetails>
<a:user>
  <a:username>Clow</a:username>
  <a:userid>9834</a:userid>
</a:user>
<a:user>
  <a:username>Adam</a:username>
  <a:userid>9867</a:userid>
</a:user>
</a:UserDetails>
```

UserSites.xml contains:

```
<a:UserSites>
<a:site>
  <a:createdby>9834</a:userid>
  <a:type>blog</a:type>
</a:site>
<a:site>
  <a:createdby>9867</a:username>
  <a:type>web</a:type>
</a:site>
```

What I would like to do is use data in both of these data sources to indicate which users have sites created and what type of site they have.

How can this be made possible in **XSLT 1.0**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`document` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#document) to access nodes in an external document

For example, the following stylesheet applied to `UserDetails.xml`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:a="a">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <test>
            <xsl:value-of
              select="document('UserSites.xml')/a:UserSites/a:site/a:createdby"/>
        </test>    
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Outputs the following result from `UserSites.xml`:

```
9834
```

**Note:** Your example XML is not well-formed, so I had to make minor adjustments before processing.

Comment: Sorry about the dodgy XML, and many thanks for the comphrehensive answer.